# OSError: cannot open resource while using text_to_font module

Tags: python

I am trying to make a **quotes generator** in Python. You can see my code below:

```
from quotefancy import get_quote

from text_to_font.transformations import word_to_ascii
a=get_quote(type='text')

print(word_to_ascii(
    phrase=a, 
    font_size=3, 
    kerning=1,
    font_path='~/fonts/somefont.ttf'  
))
```

While running this script I am getting this error:

[image: error]

Comment: Use absolute path like `c:/xxxx/fonts/somefont.ttf`

Comment: i changed my font path (font_path= "C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf")              but now i am getting this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dell\Downloads\jokes\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(word_to_ascii(
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\text_to_font\transformations.py", line 17, in word_to_ascii
    row_bitmap = bitmap[row]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: text_to_font has a minimum font size to work properly.  The minimum probably varies based on the font metrics.  Didn't really feel like digging into the logic too deeply to determine exactly what he's doing.  But size 7 seems large enough to work for windows Arial.